# get value from lawnchair in different page

Tags: javascript, cordova, lawnchair

Page1:

```
var done=Lawnchair({adapter:"dom",name:'done'},function(e){
console.log("storage open");
})
var obj1='false';
done.save({key:'1',value:obj1});
```

Page2:

```
Lawnchair({adapter:"dom",name:'done'},function(e){
this.get('1', function(obj) {
console.log('object is: ' + obj);
alert(obj.value);
 })
```

I am getting the error **TypeError:obj is null**

Comment: Please add a little more context about the problem. How are these pages related? What have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: In Page1 i have saved the data in the done object and when the back button is pressed in the app... in current page it has to retreive the value which was stored the previous page...yes i have tried to solve the problem

Comment: Use another adapter, local storage for example.

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError:obj is null` means that Lawnchair `done` db was not yet created. If it does it would display and alert `false`.

Do confirm that you we're able to create a `done` db.

```
var done=Lawnchair({adapter:"dom",name:'done'},function(e){
    console.log("storage open");
});

var obj1='false';
done.save({key:'1',value:obj1}, function(k) {
    console.log(k)
});
```

After you saved `key:'1'` it will out the object data. If it won't, double check if you have included the dom.js adapter.